# execl in a detached thread - killing the process (c++ std 11)

Tags: c++, multithreading, exec

consider this

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <cmath>
#include <thread>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

#include "utils.cpp"
#include "pstream.h" 
//pstream is the process stream library as below
void doThings()
{
while(not exitflag, a global){
if(some condition) {execl (a bash script); std:cout << "this text will never get printed, process ends at execl" <<endl;}
}}}

int main()
{//detach  doThings as a thread here

}
```

i can guarantee that the global exitflag is not set, also, the std::cout line would have been printed, even the flag was set , because there is no command to break and jump to the end of the while to felicitate the termination before printing the message.

what did i do wrong? BTW: the shell script is working perfectly.

edit : (thanks minitech) I did not want the orginal program to die

pthreads : http://sourceforge.net/projects/pstreams/files/pstreams/Release%200.8.x/

Comment: I have no idea what you’re asking here. Could you show what output you’re getting and what you expect instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`execl`'s documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl)

> The exec() family of functions **replaces the current process image with
>   a new process image**. The functions described in this manual page are
>   front-ends for execve(2). (See the manual page for execve(2) for
>   further details about the replacement of the current process image.)

You should **always** call [`fork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) before calling `execl` if you don't want the original program to die.

Comment: Not always, but almost always.  The reasons for not calling `fork()` first tend to be oddball cases, like a SUID wrapper program that needs to adjust something in the process's environment before running another program (though that would most usually use `execv()` or `execve()` — and not usually `execvp()` — since it would probably pass the user's arguments to the executed program.  However, to a first approximation, 'always' will do.  And you're absolutely right that `exec*()` terminates all threads in a process.

Comment: Just edited the answer, thanks for the wake-up call :)

Comment: thank you, you are a hero - such a silly mistake from my side, grr